# Since $~P(X) ~\bot~ x-P(X)~ $, we have $~||x||^2=||p(x)||^2+||x-P(x) ||^2~$

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, projection, projection-matrices

"Since $~P(X)  \ \bot ~\ x -P(X) ~$, we have $~||x||^2=||p(x)||^2+||x-P(x) ||^2~$ ". Can someone please explain why this is true?

Since $~P(X)  \ \bot ~\ x -P(X) ~$, we have $~||x||^2=||p(x)||^2+||x-P(x) ||^2~$.  thus $||x||^2$=$ \langle x,x \rangle $ =$||P(x)||^2$ +||x-$P(x)||^2$.

Therefore, $||P(x)||^2 \leq ||x||^2. since ||P(x)||\geq 0$ and $||x||\geq 0, we have ||P(x)||\leq ||x||$.

We jump to the conclusion of $||P(x)||^2 \leq ||x||^2.$ because of $  ||P(x)||\geq 0$ and $||x||\geq 0. $.

> but where do we prove that $||P(x)||\geq 0$ and $||x||\geq 0$ in the
>   first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x \perp y$ then $$\|x+y\|^{2}=\langle (x+y) , (x+y) \rangle$$ $$ =\langle x , x \rangle +\langle x , y \rangle+\langle y , x \rangle+\langle y , y \rangle=\|x\|^{2}+0+0+\|y\|^{2}.$$

Replace $x$ by $Px$ and $y$ by $x-Px$ in this.

Comment: What exactly is ||x+y|| and $||+y||^2$?

Comment: I have added one more line. Is it clear now? @momomo

Comment: Can you please also take a look at the updated question since I thought I would be able to figure out the rest with the hints, but still got stuck .

Comment: Do you know what a norm is and what an inner product is?. $\|x\|^{2}$ is just the square of the norm of $x$.

Comment: ok, so in this case X is a vector and P(x) is a vector. then the result of x-p(x) is another vector, then we calculate the norm of (x-p(x)), then square it,   is the norm a vector or scalar ?

Comment: Norm is a scalar.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u:=p(x)$ and $v: =x-p(x).$ Then $u \perp v$, therefore, by Pythagoras:

$$||x||^2=||u+v||^2=||u||^2+||v||^2.$$